# Populate TwinColSelect via ComboBox

Tags: java, vaadin

i have the following trouble. I have a ComboBox that contains a list of districts, now when the value of the comboBox change, i have to change also the value of the left column of the TwinColSelect  but the right column has to remain the same.

How can I do?

Comment: I have stumbled into the same issue. The answer is not clear to me. do you have a code snippet that I can take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to extends TwinColSelect and in there set the `containerDataSource` and `setValue` by yourself on

Example:

```
public class MyTwinColSelect
    extends TwinColSelect {

   public MyTwinColSelect(List<T> dataSource, List<T> value) {
      setContainerDataSource(new BeanItemContainer<T>(dataSource));
      setValue(value);
   }

   public updateDataSource(List<T> newDataSource) {
      setContainerDataSource(new BeanItemContainer<T>(newDataSource));
   }
}
```

And for ComboBox:

```
comboBox.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener() {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Override
   public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
      twincolselect.updateDataSource(newDataSource);
   }
});
```